# Cannot convert value of type '(NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: ios, arrays, double, nsdate, nstimeinterval

[Docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTimeInterval) that `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate()` returns `NSTimeInterval` which is a typealias for a Double.

I am not 100% sure what a `typealias` is. Basically, if my function needs a `Double`, how can I get the `Double` from `NSTimeInterval`.

```
var t_start: NSDate = NSDate()


//**THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS**
mCloud.saveSessionDuration(PFUser.currentUser()!, duration:     NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start))
```

The function `saveSessionDuration` is as follows:

```
func saveSessionDuration(usr: PFUser, duration: Double) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

timeIntervalSinceDate is not a class method. Maybe you can try

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start)
```